# Is there a publicly available street centerline file that can be used to geocode Westchester addresses?

Tags: data, geocoding

The publicly available file at NYSGIS Clearinghouse does not have the required fields to geocode Westchester addresses. The file available for cooperating members does have them, but my institution is not a cooperative member.

Comment: This looks like a question that would be suitable for asking at the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange but, if you decide to, be sure to review their help to be confident that it is on topic first.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try the [OSM](https://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100) data.
2. Most people use APIs now. Many exist. The Google geocoding [API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro) is very popular.
3. Never ignore the [TIGER](https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-line.html) lines.
4. Does [Winchester GIS](http://giswww.westchestergov.com/wcgis/Data.htm) department give it out free. Ask them.

I would do 2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the info for NY State Geocoding Services. There is an ArcGIS Rest service to hit.

http://gis.ny.gov/gisdata/inventories/details.cfm?DSID=1278

http://gis.ny.gov/streets/